# Authentication laravel 4.2 cannot work

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

Authentication laravel can't work on my program. I have googled but not solve this. My program is

LoginController@auth

```
public function auth()
{
    $username = Input::get('username');
    $password = Input::get('pass');
    if(Auth::attempt(array('id' => $username, 'password' => $password))) 
    {
        echo "Work";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "Bad";
    }
}
```

Authtable.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class Authtable extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface 
{

protected $table = 'authtable';

protected $hidden = array('password');

/**
 * Get the unique identifier for the user.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getAuthIdentifier()
{
    return $this->getKey();
}

/**
 * Get the password for the user.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getReminderEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

public function getRememberToken()
{
    return $this->remember_token;
}

public function setRememberToken($value)
{
    $this->remember_token = $value;
}

public function getRememberTokenName()
{
    return 'remember_token';
}
```

}

auth.php

```
'driver' => 'eloquent',
'model' => 'Authtable',
'table' => 'authtable',
```

And nullable remember_token(varchar(100)), password(varchar(60)) but still not work. Please give some solution.

Comment: can you post your auth config file

Answer (score 0):

I had a bad experience about that.

- `Composer dump-autoload` to make sure model name is working.
- Check that model name has no conflicts
- Check 'authtable' column names. Is that columns include what you Input?`'id' => $username, 'password' => $password`